# How to compare two values with other three values аnd to visualize all the rows that meet the condition using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I need to make a flood warning system and compare two values `level_11` and `level_fw` with these three values `ALERT_yewoll` `ALERT_orange` and `ALERT_red` from this [api](http://194.141.118.43:3010/alldata).

For now I do the check this way, but when I replace `MikeAllData.ALERT_yewoll` with manual value for example 225.50 (this is for [0] index in the rows) I see only one row, but I need to see all rows which meet the condition.

```
const urlCheckForWarnings = 'http://194.141.118.43:3010/alldata';
// Create Asynchronous function to grab the data 
async function getDataWarningsMikeFW() {
    try {
        // We are using fetch to get the response
        const responseAllData = await fetch(urlCheckForWarnings);
        const allDataModels = await responseAllData.json();
        // Trigger the listData function and pass the result
        listValues(allDataModels);
        console.log(allDataModels);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function listValues(allDataModels) {
    // Loop through each result and append the data.
    allDataModels.floodguard_alldata.rows.map(function (AllData, i) {
        const formatDate = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";

        if (AllData.level_11 >= 222.50 /*MikeAllData.ALERT_yewoll*/ && AllData.level_11 < 222.50 /*MikeAllData.ALERT_orange*/) {
            document.getElementById("mikeFWwarnings").innerHTML = "Предупреждение 1: Жълт код за: " + AllData.substring + " за дата: " + moment(AllData.date).format(formatDate);
        }

        if (AllData.level_11 >= AllData.ALERT_orange && AllData.level_11 < AllData.ALERT_red) {
            document.getElementById("mikeFWwarnings").innerHTML = "Предупреждение 2: Оранжев код за: " + AllData.substring + " за дата: " + moment(AllData.date).format(formatDate);
        }

        if (AllData.level_11 >= AllData.ALERT_red) {
            document.getElementById("mikeFWwarnings").innerHTML = "Предупреждение 3: Червен код за: " + AllData.substring + " за дата: " + moment(AllData.date).format(formatDate);
        }

        if (AllData.level_fw >= 222.50 /*MikeAllData.ALERT_yewoll*/ && AllData.level_fw < 222.50 /*MikeAllData.ALERT_orange*/) {
            document.getElementById("mikeFWwarnings").innerHTML = "Предупреждение 1: Жълт код за: " + AllData.substring + " за дата: " + moment(AllData.date).format(formatDate);;
        }

        if (AllData.level_fw >= AllData.ALERT_orange && AllData.level_fw < AllData.ALERT_red) {
            document.getElementById("mikeFWwarnings").innerHTML = "Предупреждение 2: Оранжев код за: " + AllData.substring + " за дата: " + moment(AllData.date).format(formatDate);;
        }

        if (AllData.level_fw >= AllData.ALERT_red) {
            document.getElementById("mikeFWwarnings").innerHTML = "Предупреждение 3: Червен код за: " + AllData.substring + " за дата: " + moment(AllData.date).format(formatDate);;
        }
    });
};

getDataWarningsMikeFW();
```

The condition I have to do is if values of `level_fw` and `level_11` are in the range between `ALERT_yewoll` `ALERT_orange` and `ALERT_red` To set Code 1, Code 2 or Code 3 warning messages.

I'm not sure if my check is correct and how can I visualize all indexes that meet the condition and not just the first index?

Comment: At the moment, every single warning is output in the same place (the text of the `mikeFWwarnings` element), so you only get *one* warning (being the last one processed). The possible warnings are: (1) level 11 between yellow and orange, (2) level 11 between orange and red, (3) level 11 above red, (4) level fw between yellow and orange, (5) level fw between orange and red, and (6) level fw above red, and each of those six warnings for each row of the data. What exactly do you want displayed? The worst level 11 and worst fw warning for each row of data? Do you know the number of rows beforehand?

Comment: First thing you need to do is make sure your HTML page has the elements on it to contain the information, and then you can loop through the information and fill in those elements with the data.

Comment: Can I get some example how to do that ?

Comment: I want as many lines as there are to be displayed as a message because they have different times and dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a pretty rough and ready example of how you can add and remove elements on your page and populate the correct elements with the right warnings.

```js
// CONSTANTS
let YELLOW = 500;
let ORANGE = 750;
let RED = 1000;

// DATA
let dataSetOne = [
    {"level_11": 600, "level_fw": 800},
    {"level_11": 800, "level_fw": 400},
    {"level_11": 400, "level_fw": 1200}
];
let dataSetTwo = [
    {"level_11": 200, "level_fw": 400},
    {"level_11": 1200, "level_fw": 700},
    {"level_11": 300, "level_fw": 800},
    {"level_11": 1200, "level_fw": 1200},
    {"level_11": 800, "level_fw": 600},
]
// ELEMENTS
let warningBox = document.getElementById("warningBox");

// BUTTONS
document.getElementById("buttonOne").addEventListener("click", () => listValues(dataSetOne))
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").addEventListener("click", () => listValues(dataSetTwo))

// FUNCTIONS
function listValues(allDataModels) {
    getRightNumberOfWarningElements(allDataModels);
    allDataModels.forEach ((data, index) =>
        fillInRowWarnings(data, index + 1)
    )
}

function fillInRowWarnings(data, row) {
    let element_11 = document.getElementById(warningRowChildId(row, "11"))
    let element_fw = document.getElementById(warningRowChildId(row, "fw"))
    element_11.innerText = getWarningText(data.level_11);
    element_fw.innerText = getWarningText(data.level_fw);
}

function getWarningText(value) {
    if (value < YELLOW)
     return "No warning"
  else if (value < ORANGE)
     return "Yellow warning"
  else if (value < RED)
     return "Orange warning"
  else return "Red warning"
}

function getRightNumberOfWarningElements(allDataModels) {
    if (allDataModels.length > warningBox.childElementCount)
        addWarningElements(warningBox.childElementCount, allDataModels.length);
    if (allDataModels.length < warningBox.childElementCount)
        removeWarningElements(warningBox.childElementCount, allDataModels.length);
}

function addWarningElements(from, to) {
    for (i = from + 1; i<= to; i++)
        warningBox.appendChild(createWarningRow(i))
}

function removeWarningElements(from, to) {
    for (i = from; i>= to + 1; i--)
        warningBox.removeChild(warningBox.lastChild)
}

function createWarningRow(number) {
    let row = document.createElement("div")
    row.setAttribute("id", "warningRow" + number);
    let rowTitle = document.createElement("h4");
    rowTitle.innerText = "Row " + number;
    row.appendChild(rowTitle);
    addSubTitle(row, "11")
    addNewRowChild(row, number, "11");
    addSubTitle(row, "fw")
    addNewRowChild(row, number, "fw");
    return row;
}

function addSubTitle(row, subTitleText) {
    let subTitle = document.createElement("h5");
    subTitle.innerText = "Level " + subTitleText;
    row.appendChild(subTitle);
}

function addNewRowChild(row, rowNumber, levelType) {
    let newChild = document.createElement("p")
    newChild.setAttribute("id", warningRowChildId(rowNumber, levelType));
    row.appendChild(newChild)
}

function warningRowChildId(rowNumber, levelType) {
    return "warningRow_" + rowNumber + "_level_" + levelType
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="buttonOne">Data set one</button>
<button type="button" id="buttonTwo">Data set two</button>
<div id="warningBox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```